# How to add custom ClientValidationRules (unobtrusive validation) for a complex type on a model?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Say I have a custom validation attribute `ValidateFooIsCompatibleWith` model like so:

```
public class FooPart
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    public string Eey { get; set; }
}

public class FooableViewModel
{
    public FooPart Foo1 { get; set; }

    [ValidateFooIsCompatibleWith("Foo1")]
    public FooPart Foo2 { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say I also have custom EditorTemplates defined for `FooPart`:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Foo)
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Eey)
```

And thus my view is essentially:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Foo1)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Foo2)
```

Server side, the validation works fine.  However, no matter what I try, I can't get the rendered html to add the rule.

If I implement `IClientValidatable`, it turns out that `GetClientValidationRules()` never gets called. (I have successfully used `IClientValidatable` with "simple" fields before).

I also tried registering my own custom adapter by inheriting from `DataAnnotationsModelValidator<TAttribute>` and registering it in the `global.asax` with `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(...)` That approach too fails to call `GetClientValidationRules()`.

** Update **
If a add both a custom `ModelMetadataProvider` and a custom `ModelValidatorProvider` so that I can set breakpoints, I notice an interesting bit of behavior:

- a request is made to the `ModelMetadataProvider` for metadata with a `ContainerType` of `FooableViewModel` and a `ModelType` of `FooPart`. However, no corresponding request is made to the `ModelValidatorProvider`, so I can't insert my custom client validation rules there.
- requests are made to the `ModelValidatorProvider` with a `ContainerType` of `FooPart` and a `ModelType` of `string` for both the `Foo` and `Eey` properties. But at this level, I don't know the attributes applied to the `FooPart` property.

How can I get the MVC framework to register my custom client validation rules for complex types?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

First, Create a custom model metadata provider (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20983571/24954) that checks the attributes on the complex type, and stores a client validatable rule factory in the `AdditionalValues` collection, e.g. in the `CreateMetadataProtoype` override of the `CachedDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`

```
 var ruleFactories = new List<Func<ModelMetadata, ControllerContext, IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRules>>>();
 ...
 var clientValidatable = (IClientValidatable)attribute;
 ruleFactories.Add(clientValidatable.GetClientValidationRules);
 ...
 result.AdditionalValues.Add("mycachekey", ruleFactories);
```

Next, register this as the default metadata provider in the global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new MyCustomModelMetadataProvider();
    ....
}
```

Then I created an html helper that would process the modelmetata and create/merge the "data-val*" html attributes from each of `AdditionalValues` collection.

```
public static IDictionary<string, Object> MergeHtmlAttributes<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel>, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    var attributesDictionary = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    //ensure data dictionary has unobtrusive validation enabled for the element
    attributesDictionary.Add("data-val", "true");

    //loop through all the rule factories, and execute each factory to get all the rules
    var rules = ruleFactory(helper.Html.ViewData.ModelMetadata, helper.Html.ViewContext);

    //loop through and execute all rules in the ruleFactory collection in the AdditionalValues
    //and add the data-val attributes for those.
    attributesDictionary.add("data-val-" + rule.ValidationType, ruleErrorMessage);

    //similarly for anything in the rule.ValidationParameters
    attributesDictionary.Add("data-val-" + rule.ValidationType + "-" + parameterName, parameterValue);

}
```

Finally, in my editor template, call the html helper (which has a model type of `FooPart1) for each complex type property, e.g.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Foo, Html.MergeHtmlAttributes(new { @class="Bar"}))
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Eey, Html.MergeHtmlAttributes())
```

I actually ended up creating a second interface (with the same signature as `IClientValidatable`) that allowed me to customize rules (primarily for error messages) for the individual fields of a complex type.  I also extended the helper to take a string argument that could be formatted with my custom rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#foo" ).validate({
rules: 
{
   rule1: {required: true, min: 3},
   parent: 
   {
        required: function(element) {return $("#age").val() < 13;}    
   }
 }
});
```

Complex types seem to hassle me for no good reason so try the Jquery validator. Depending on what you're trying to validate it might get the job done.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the EditorTemplate for `FooPart`, I need to apply validation based on the validations of the property - e.g. in the example in the question, the editor template for `FooPart` sometimes needs to add the client validation rules e.g. `ValidateFooIsCompatibleWith` (which are using the jquery unobtrusive validation), and sometimes not.  So jquery validator is part of the solution, but I don't think that this solves my fundamental problem.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your problem because your using the server to send validation rules to the client opposed to handling client validation via JS or Jquery. Have you tried `CustomValidationAttribute`?